# Ranking in Tableau Based on another Field

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api, ranking

How to rank based on a field where the value is the same. There is some more ranking applied here and this scenario need to be addressed as well as *I can not rank again by Sales field*. Instead, I need to say:
**If Unit is the same on the list of territories, rank based on Sales.**

Example:

```
Terr       Sales   Unit   Should look like : Terr       Sales   Unit      
----      ------   -----                    -----------------------
Boston       1      5                        Maine      10     5
Maine       10      5                        Boston      1     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Often a mathematical approach works well for this. First, without wanting to patronise, it's possible to use a discrete (blue) measure to sort data. Place the sorting pill to the far left on the Rows and the table will sort according to this pill.

Ok, so the formula. Without knowing how large the Sales figure can go, you want to create a calculation that would give the highest value to that you want to appear top.

For example perhaps multiple Unit by 1,000,000 and add Sales. Just make sure the Units are multiplied by a number large enough to make Sales inconsequential.

This field may work, depending how large the Sales figure can go:

[SortField] = (SUM([Unit])*1000000 + SUM([Sales])) * -1

Put the field to Rows, convert to Discrete, then place to the far left. If the sorting is correct hide the field header.

It multiplies by -1 to sort descending.